# Transformation nonlinear PDE to system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How I can transform this PDE to system of ODE 
$$a^2 u_{tt}-u_{xx}+ u \cdot u_x = 0$$

I trying to use the following transformation $p=u_{t}$ and $q=u_{x}$
then the equation be 
$p_{t}- (1/ a^2)*q_{x} + (1/ a^2)*u*q = 0$
my question now how I can change the $u$ in last term, and what is the ordinary system equation for the original problem ?

Answer (score 4):

A second order pde is not usually equivalent to a system of ode's. But if you want to just find some solutions using an ode, you can look for traveling waves $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$. Substituting, you need $a^2c^2f''-f''+ff'=0$. So take $c$ to be any speed
other than $1/a$. Integrate once to get $(a^2c^2-1)f'+\frac{1}{2}f^2 = $ constant.
That leaves you with a 1st order ode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is coming to my mind now the following question : What is the necessary conditions we need to transform second order PDE to a system of ODE.